# Updating the state of toggle button by getting on/off value from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to control my switch by getting value from firebase database. Its listening to the value whenever it is changed but i dont understand how to use that value to toggle the button. This is basically an app in which you can control the hardware switch via app and app via hardware with firebase as a bridge between them.

```
child: LiteRollingSwitch(
    value: state,
    textOn: 'active',
    textOff: 'inactive',
    colorOn: Colors.lightGreen,
    colorOff: Colors.deepOrange,
    iconOn: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
    iconOff: Icons.power_settings_new,
    onChanged: (bool value) async{
      print('turned ${(value) ? 'on' : 'off'}');
      final databasereference2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      final FirebaseAuth _auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      final uid = user.uid;
      final username=user.email;
      var currDt = DateTime.now();
      if(value==true)
      {
        databasereference2.child('users').child(uid).child('Activity log').child('2020').child(currDt.month.toString()).child('day'+currDt.day.toString()).push().set({'state': 'on','switch id':'bed bulb','time':currDt.hour.toString()+':'+currDt.minute.toString()+':'+currDt.second.toString()});
        databasereference2.child('users').child(uid).child('Live Status').child('bedroom').child('bedbulb').set('on');
      }
      else{databasereference2.child('users').child(uid).child('Activity log').child('2020').child(currDt.month.toString()).child('day'+currDt.day.toString()).push().set({'state': 'on','switch id':'bed bulb','time':currDt.hour.toString()+':'+currDt.minute.toString()+':'+currDt.second.toString()});
      databasereference2.child('users').child(uid).child('Live Status').child('bedroom').child('bedbulb').set('off');}
```

The part where i am listening is:

```
databasereference2.child('users').child(uid).child('Live Status').child('bedroom').onValue.listen((event) {
        var snapshot = event.snapshot;
        var x = snapshot.value['bedbulb'];
        print(x);
        if (x == 'on') {setState(() {
          value=true;
          print(value);
          state=value;
          print(state);


        });
        }
        else{
          setState(() {
            value=false;
            print(value);
            state=value;
            print(state);
          });
        }
      }
      );
    },
  ),
```

Please help me in using the value listened to toggle the button. This toggle switch is from flutter library LiteRollingSwitch and its code is here:

```
library lite_rolling_switch;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class LiteRollingSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final bool value;
  @required
  final Function(bool) onChanged;
  final String textOff;
  final String textOn;
  final Color colorOn;
  final Color colorOff;
  final double textSize;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final IconData iconOn;
  final IconData iconOff;
  final Function onTap;
  final Function onDoubleTap;
  final Function onSwipe;
  final Function toggleswitch;

  LiteRollingSwitch(
      {this.value = false,
      this.textOff = "Off",
      this.textOn = "On",
      this.textSize = 14.0,
      this.colorOn = Colors.green,
      this.colorOff = Colors.red,
      this.iconOff = Icons.flag,
      this.iconOn = Icons.check,
      this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      this.onTap,
      this.onDoubleTap,
      this.onSwipe, this.toggleswitch,
      this.onChanged});

  @override
  _RollingSwitchState createState() => _RollingSwitchState();
}

class _RollingSwitchState extends State<LiteRollingSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  double value = 0.0;
  final databasereference2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  bool turnState;




  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        lowerBound: 0.0,
        upperBound: 1.0,
        duration: widget.animationDuration);
    animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        value = animation.value;
      });
    });
    turnState = widget.value;
    _determine();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color transitionColor = Color.lerp(widget.colorOff, widget.colorOn, value);

    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () {
        _action();
        if (widget.onDoubleTap != null) widget.onDoubleTap();
      },
      onTap: () {
        _action();
        if (widget.onTap != null) widget.onTap();
      },
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        _action();
        if (widget.onSwipe != null) widget.onSwipe();
        //widget.onSwipe();
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        width: 130,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: transitionColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(10 * value, 0), //original
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: (1 - value).clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  height: 40,
                  child: Text(
                    widget.textOff,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: widget.textSize),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(10 * (1 - value), 0), //original
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: value.clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(/*top: 10,*/ left: 5),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  height: 40,
                  child: Text(
                    widget.textOn,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: widget.textSize),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(80 * value, 0),
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: lerpDouble(0, 2 * pi, value),
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: Opacity(
                          opacity: (1 - value).clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            widget.iconOff,
                            size: 25,
                            color: transitionColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                          child: Opacity(
                              opacity: value.clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                widget.iconOn,
                                size: 21,
                                color: transitionColor,
                              ))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _action() {
    _determine(changeState: true);
  }

  _determine({bool changeState = false}) {
    setState(() {
      if (changeState) turnState = !turnState;
      (turnState)
          ? animationController.forward()
          : animationController.reverse();

      widget.onChanged(turnState);
    });
  }
}
```